# (Flutter) does file IO async functions run in a separate isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to check existence of many (~100) files on disk, and want to do it in a background isolate.

I have two options:

Option#1:
Write a helper function that **synchronously** checks the existence of files one by one (`File('...').existsSync()`);
then explicitly call `await compute()` to make sure the util function runs in background isolate.

Option#2:
Simply do:

```dart
final List<bool> exists = Future.wait(filenames.map((fn) => File(fn).exists());
```

But it won't work if the async `exists()` functions also runs in UI isolate.

--> So will `File.exists()` automatically spawn and run on a new isolate?

Comment: [Asynchronous I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) uses asynchronous I/O primitives from the OS.  They won't necessarily (and likely won't) run in a separate Dart isolate but might use hardware interrupts, threads, etc..  You shouldn't be concerned with the exact mechanism.  If you're doing *many* filesystem operations, it's much more efficient to use async I/O since operations typically will be batched for you.